# Only work with upto 8 decimal places in Octave

Tags: octave

When the eigenvalues of matrices with integer entries (even 3x3 matrices) are calculated in Octave, sometimes it reports a floating point value like 9.1940e-17, whereas it should really be zero.
For example, when I am plotting some numbers *modulo 1*, a value -2e-17 is becoming 1 in the plot, but it should actually be 0.

Although I can approximate the answers upto some decimal places later, it will still internally calculate upto 17 decimal places while calculating the eigenvalue and waste calculation time. Is it possible to work with only upto something like 8 decimal places for all quantities from the beginning?

If that is not possible, is it possible to tell octave (once and for all in a script) to approximate all quantities upto 8 decimal places while reporting?

Comment: Please note that I am not asking why floating-point numbers cannot be exactly represented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement [Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61212694/7328782), the additional precision doesn't cost any additional time. The computer works with the number as a whole, not with individual digits.

You might want to use

```
A(abs(A)<1e-8) = 0;
```

after computing your final result `A` to set the near-zero values to zero.

Comment: Do I have to do this for each matrix element, or will it work for the whole matrix?

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for won't help, it makes it worse. Setting the precision to 8 decimal points (or significant digits) won't make numerical errors disappear, it will increase the numerical errors to that magnitude. Take a simple calculation:

```
x=1/3
y=x*6
```

Now you would end up with `1.99999998`, a much larger error.

There are libraries doing the opposite, increasing the precision. In Octave that's called [vpa](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/vpa.html).